# Build array from string consisting of elements with the same beginning and end (tags)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I'm trying to build an array from a long string which consists of text somewhat similar to HTML, but actually not valid HTML. It looks like this:

```
<span class="Latn form-of lang-la 1|s|pres|act|ind-form-of   origin-audeō   " lang="la">[[audeo#Latin|audeō]]</span> +
'|- class="vsHide"\n' +
      '| <span class="Latn form-of lang-la 3|p|pres|act|sub-form-of   origin-audeō   " lang="la">[[audeant#Latin|audeant]]</span>\n
```

What I would like to do is create an array from this string, consisting of elements starting with `<span` and ending with `</span>`

I have already looked at a method like string split, but that also keeps the content in between the `<span>` elements (which I don't want). The array I would like to return is something like this:

```
[
    '<span class="Latn form-of ....." lang="la">.....</span>',
    '<span class="Latn form-of ....." lang="la">.....</span>'
]
```

And then of course resembling the `<span>` tags like they are present in the string, with all its content between the opening and closing tag.

How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: Regular expressions

Comment: You may try this to generate regular expression for javascript: https://regex101.com/ or any other website of this kind.